# Missing help topic: color codes in questions list

Tags: feature-request, questions, help-center

Questions with accepted answers have their answer square in green, otherwise it is transparent.

Questions matching your watched tags have a red background.

The system is quite simple once you get the idea - yet there is no help topic explaining it and I consider it missing.
Being new to the site (and especially when new to linux, where you will be stuck with basic unterstandings of the OS), I assume that one will find answers quicker knowing when a question has an accepted answer.

You can also call it a matter of principle especially for a UNIX-themed site that there better be a proper documentation....

[image]